# Wrong estimated row count

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan

**PostgreSQL 11**

Running EXPLAIN returns a row estimate that is way too low compared to the actual row count.

Given the query

```
    SELECT s.offer_id,
    category_id, category_name_de, category_name_fr, category_name_it, seller_id, seller_nickname, title, offer_type, 
    condition, ends_at, current_price, buynow_price, CASE WHEN bid_count = 0 THEN current_price ELSE current_price + increment END AS next_minimum_bid, 
    bid_count, quantity, 
    ub.max_bid, ub.is_standing_bid 
    FROM data.saved_articles AS s 
    LEFT JOIN aggregated.users_bids ub ON s.user_id = ub.user_id AND s.offer_id = ub.offer_id
    JOIN aggregated.offers AS o ON s.offer_id = o.offer_id 
    WHERE s.user_id = 406943491 
    AND ends_at >= now() AND ub.is_standing_bid IS NULL
```

The `EXPLAIN` returns:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=98.80..13593.76 rows=1 width=165) (actual time=0.671..62.105 rows=3905 loops=1)
  Output: s.offer_id, o.category_id, o.category_name_de, o.category_name_fr, o.category_name_it, o.seller_id, o.seller_nickname, o.title, o.offer_type, o.condition, o.ends_at, o.current_price, o.buynow_price, CASE WHEN (o.bid_count = 0) THEN o.current_price ELSE (o.current_price + o.increment) END, o.bid_count, o.quantity, ub.max_bid, ub.is_standing_bid
  Inner Unique: true
  Buffers: shared hit=37886 dirtied=98
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=98.38..13587.37 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.572..4.722 rows=9402 loops=1)
        Output: s.offer_id, ub.max_bid, ub.is_standing_bid
        Inner Unique: true
        Merge Cond: (s.offer_id = ub.offer_id)
        Join Filter: (s.user_id = ub.user_id)
        Filter: (ub.is_standing_bid IS NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 8
        Buffers: shared hit=239
        ->  Index Only Scan using pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id on data.saved_articles s  (cost=0.43..13468.13 rows=8465 width=8) (actual time=0.020..2.300 rows=9410 loops=1)
              Output: s.user_id, s.offer_id
              Index Cond: (s.user_id = 406943491)
              Heap Fetches: 9410
              Buffers: shared hit=89
        ->  Sort  (cost=97.94..98.00 rows=24 width=13) (actual time=0.548..0.603 rows=229 loops=1)
              Output: ub.max_bid, ub.is_standing_bid, ub.user_id, ub.offer_id
              Sort Key: ub.offer_id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 35kB
              Buffers: shared hit=150
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on aggregated.users_bids ub  (cost=4.61..97.39 rows=24 width=13) (actual time=0.051..0.483 rows=229 loops=1)
                    Output: ub.max_bid, ub.is_standing_bid, ub.user_id, ub.offer_id
                    Recheck Cond: (ub.user_id = 406943491)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=147
                    Buffers: shared hit=150
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_users_bids__user_id_offer_id  (cost=0.00..4.61 rows=24 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=229 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (ub.user_id = 406943491)
                          Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Index Scan using pk_offers_offer_id on aggregated.offers o  (cost=0.43..6.39 rows=1 width=156) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=9402)
        Output: o.offer_id, o.seller_id, o.seller_nickname, o.title, o.condition, o.ends_at, o.current_price, o.buynow_price, o.category_id, o.category_name_fr, o.category_name_de, o.category_name_it, o.created_at, o.updated_at, o.bid_count, o.quantity, o.increment, o.offer_type
        Index Cond: (o.offer_id = s.offer_id)
        Filter: (o.ends_at >= now())
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=37647 dirtied=98
Planning Time: 0.601 ms
Execution Time: 62.363 ms
```

I ran a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` before the explain.

Note that the nested loop row count estimate is 1 but the actual is almost 4k. This leads me to think a nested loop here might not be the fastest option.

Is this a problem and can I make this query faster?

#### Tables & indexes

```
CREATE TABLE aggregated.offers
(
    offer_id integer NOT NULL,
    seller_id integer NOT NULL,
    seller_nickname character varying(30),
    title character varying(60),
    condition character varying(50),
    ends_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    current_price bigint,
    buynow_price bigint,
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    category_name_fr character varying,
    category_name_de character varying,
    category_name_it character varying,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    bid_count integer NOT NULL,
    quantity integer NOT NULL,
    increment integer,
    offer_type text,
    CONSTRAINT pk_offers_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (offer_id)
)

ALTER TABLE aggregated.offers
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_offers_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (offer_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_offers_seller_id ON aggregated.offers (seller_id);

CREATE TABLE data.saved_articles (
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    offer_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_saved_articles_offer_id FOREIGN KEY (offer_id)
        REFERENCES aggregated.offers (offer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE INDEX idx_saved_articles_offer_id ON data.saved_articles (offer_id);
CREATE TABLE aggregated.users_bids
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    offer_id integer NOT NULL,
    max_bid integer,
    is_standing_bid boolean,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_users_bids__user_id_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id)
)
```

Comment: I'm missing at least the column `ends_at` in your table definitions.

Comment: @Colin'tHart You're right, edited with the correct table definition.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the size of `offer`: if the table is large, the nested loop join might still be the most efficient option.

You can try

```
SET enable_nestloop = off;
```

and see if that improves the execution time or not.

The mis-estimate may be caused by a correlation between `offer_id` and `user_id` across the two tables, but unfortunately there is no way that I know of to fix that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why creating statistics for `user_id` and `offer_id ` wouldn't help?
`CREATE STATISTICS saved_articles_user_id_offer_id_stat ON user_id, offer_id FROM data.saved_articles;
CREATE STATISTICS saved_articles_user_id_offer_id_stat ON user_id, offer_id FROM data.saved_articles;
CREATE STATISTICS users_bids_user_id_offer_id_stat ON user_id, offer_id FROM aggregated.users_bids;`

Comment: @DenisStafichuk Perhaps worth a try. But it won't help with cross-table correlation.